# How to calculate hours between two as.characters with the format "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm"

Tags: r, dataframe, time, dplyr, lubridate

I have `u` with `time1` and `time2` both listed with the format `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm`. I would like to produce a new covariate containing the `hours` between `u$time1` and `u$time2`.

They are listed as `as.character`

```
str(u)
'data.frame':   5765 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ time1: chr  "30-01-2020 07:20" "25-04-2019 15:05" "11-01-2019 22:01" "11-01-2019 22:01" ...
 $ time2: chr  "14-02-2020 15:34" "27-04-2019 10:56" "12-01-2019 00:42" "23-01-2019 10:08" ...
```

The expected output

```
>  head(u)
             time1            time2                            new
1 30-01-2020 07:20 14-02-2020 15:34  hours between time1 and time2
2 25-04-2019 15:05 27-04-2019 10:56  hours between time1 and time2
3 11-01-2019 22:01 12-01-2019 00:42  hours between time1 and time2
4 11-01-2019 22:01 23-01-2019 10:08  hours between time1 and time2
```

I would prefer if the hours had one decimal point, and a solution with `dplyr` or `lubridate` would be preferred.

```
u <- structure(list(time1 = c("30-01-2020 07:20", "25-04-2019 15:05", 
"11-01-2019 22:01", "11-01-2019 22:01", "17-04-2018 07:55"), 
    time2 = c("14-02-2020 15:34", "27-04-2019 10:56", "12-01-2019 00:42", 
    "23-01-2019 10:08", "20-04-2018 11:04")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: *"one decimal point"* is a data-losing operation. I suggest you do that in your final step before rendering into a report, not early in the processing. And for that, it's one of `round(.,0)` (remains a number) or `sprintf("%0.1f",.)` (now a string, no more math on this field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `difftime` after converting to `POSIXct`

```
with(u, difftime(as.POSIXct(time1, format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'), 
       as.POSIXct(time2, format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'), units = 'hour'))
```

Or as @r2evans mentioned in the comments, the `lubridate` option is

```
library(lubridate)
as.numeric(dmy_hm(u$time1) - dmy_hm(u$time2), units = "hours")
```

Comment: The arg is `units=` in case somebody has `options(warnPartialMatchArgs=TRUE)` :-)

Comment: @r2evans thanks, I always had that issue in remembering whether it is unit or units as both works

Comment: Set the option, and you won't miss it again ... until you get tired of all the packages out there that do partial-matching. I have both `warnPartialMatchDollar` and `warnPartialMatchAttr` set, but I cannot survive for long with `warnPartialMatchArgs` set.

Comment: Since they tagged [tag:lubridate], another option is `as.numeric(dmy_hm(u$time1) - dmy_hm(u$time2), units = "hours")`.

Comment: @r2evans you could post that as a separate solution as it is very different

Comment: nahh, you got it ... I prefer base anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really fast solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)


setDT(u)
u[, time1 := dmy_hm(time1)]
u[, time2 := dmy_hm(time2)]

u[, diff := difftime(time1, time2, units = "hours")]

u
>                  time1               time2              diff
> 1: 2020-01-30 07:20:00 2020-02-14 15:34:00 -368.233333 hours
> 2: 2019-04-25 15:05:00 2019-04-27 10:56:00  -43.850000 hours
> 3: 2019-01-11 22:01:00 2019-01-12 00:42:00   -2.683333 hours
> 4: 2019-01-11 22:01:00 2019-01-23 10:08:00 -276.116667 hours
> 5: 2018-04-17 07:55:00 2018-04-20 11:04:00  -75.150000 hours
```